# How do I call a function written in a kotlin class , in java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using both Kotlin and java in my codebase.
But I was wondering if there is a way I can reference a kotlin function from java?
Here's my kotlin code :
MyEvent.kt

```
open class MyEvent {
    @Inject
    lateinit var myService: MyService

    @Inject
    lateinit var app: MyApp

    var name: String = ""
    var options: MutableMap<String, String> = hashMapOf()
    var metrics: MutableMap<String, Double> = hashMapOf()

    init {
        app.component.inject(this)
    }

    fun identify() {
        myService.identify()
    }

}
```

Now, in my base application class call "MyApplication", I want to call identify function. (I . know in kotlin we can do this via MyEvent().identify ) but was wondering how do we go about it in java?
Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need other clarifications?

Comment: nah its all good. just wondering about another question. can you use companion in java? if not, what will be the equivalent for something like this :         MyEventsLogin.Companion.newBuilder().setEventName(MyEventWrapper.AUTH_VIEW).build().trackScreenEvent();

Comment: See updated answer. Hope I got what you meant right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the exact same thing in Java. Keep in mind they share the same 
underlying *bytecode*.

```
final MyEvent myEvent = new MyEvent();
myEvent.identify();
```

Look at the produced bytecode for the Kotlin `MyEvent` class (decompiled)

```
public class my/package/MyEvent {
  ...

  public final identify()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 14 L0
    RETURN // Omitted myService.identify()
  ...
```

---

A `companion` object is translated to a `static` class property in Java.
For example, for this Kotlin code

```
open class MyEvent {
    companion object {
        fun test() = ""
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the resulting bytecode

```
static <clinit>()V
    NEW my/package/MyEvent$Companion
    DUP
    ACONST_NULL
    INVOKESPECIAL my/package/MyEvent$Companion.<init> (Lkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V
    PUTSTATIC my/package/MyEvent.Companion : Lmy/package/MyEvent$Companion;
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 0
}
```

Which means, basically

```
public class MyEvent {
   public static final Companion Companion = new Companion(...);
   ...
}
```

So, in Java you'd access it using

```
MyEvent.Companion.test();
```

---

For

```
open class MyEvent {
    object Factory {
        fun test() = ""
    }
    ...
}
```

It would be, in Java

```
MyEvent.Factory.INSTANCE.test();
```

---

Ultimately Java doesn't have the concept of companion objects.
Instead, `static` properties and methods are used.